# Overlap analysis not running

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features, census

I'm trying to run QGIS's overlap analysis. I ran this a few days ago, but it's not working anymore.

I have yellow as zipcodes (overlap_zipcodes) and purple as census tracts (84_censustracts). I'm trying to calculate the percentage that census tract is in each zipcode.
[image]

I get the following error
[image]